# Creating an MKMapKit curved / spherical / interpolated camera transition

Tags: ios, mapkit

I would like to animate the camera so that the entire animation feels "curved" rather than "linear."

Right now, with the out-of-the-box camera animation iOS offers, or even when using UIView.animate(), the animation feels like the camera is directly moving from the start to the end. However, I would like the animation to feel like it is curving from the start to the end.

Here's a picture describing what it feels like now vs what I would like it to feel like.
[image: Picture]

Here is an example from Kakao maps, a Korean app, of what the desired animation would be:
[image: gif]

Currently, I'm just using two camera animations, to create a flying-out and flying-in effect. When I create my own custom animations for MKMapView's camera with a curveEaseInOut, the speed of the animation is curvedEaseInOut, but this does not create the desired effect. This creates the undesirable "linear" feeling as depicted in the "What it's now:" diagram above

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration*2,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseIn,
                   animations: {
        self.mapView.camera = preRotationCamera
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration*2,
                       delay: 0.1,
                       options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {
            self.mapView.camera = finalCamera
        }, completion: completion)
    }
```

I image that using [animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes) could be a valid approach. However, I have not been able to successfully animate the MKMapView camera through a series of coordinates with animateKeyframes() — the keyframes seemed to be ignored, and the camera just directly transitions to the final camera.

For example, this code simply transitions the camera directly to finalCamera:

```
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration*2, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeCubic, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
            self.mapView.camera = preRotationCamera
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
            self.mapView.camera = finalCamera
        }
    })
```

How could one create this kind of spherical / interpolated / curved camera transition for iOS?

For reference, this is with iOS15 and Swift 5.

Comment: I expect that you’d need to add intermediate keyframes but calculating the camera positions might be tricky.

Comment: One approach: calculate the points on an ellipse - maybe every 10 degrees, so 18-points - to get the "altitudes" and then 18-points along the x1,y1 -> x2,y2 coordinate line. Then build 18 cameras using those values. If you put together a minimal example that does your current animation, I can probably put together an example for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is now possible within SwiftUI using "mapCameraKeyframeAnimator"!

As explained in [Wind your way through advanced animations in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10157/) from WWDC23.

Here's some example code:

```
struct RaceMap: View {
    let route: Route

    @State private var trigger = false

    var body: some View {
        Map(initialPosition: .rect(route.rect)) {
            MapPolyline(coordinates: route.coordinates)
                .stroke(.orange, lineWidth: 4.0)
            Marker("Start", coordinate: route.start)
                .tint(.green)
            Marker("End", coordinate: route.end)
                .tint(.red)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Tour") { trigger.toggle() }
        }
        .mapCameraKeyframeAnimation(trigger: playTrigger) { initialCamera in
            KeyframeTrack(\MapCamera.centerCoordinate) {
                let points = route.points
                for point in points {
                    CubicKeyframe(point.coordinate, duration: 16.0 / Double(points.count))
                }
                CubicKeyframe(initialCamera.centerCoordinate, duration: 4.0)
            }
            KeyframeTrack(\.heading) {
                CubicKeyframe(heading(from: route.start.coordinate, to: route.end.coordinate), duration: 6.0)
                CubicKeyframe(heading(from: route.end.coordinate, to: route.end.coordinate), duration: 8.0)
                CubicKeyframe(initialCamera.heading, duration: 6.0)
            }
            KeyframeTrack(\.distance) {
                CubicKeyframe(24000, duration: 4)
                CubicKeyframe(18000, duration: 12)
                CubicKeyframe(initialCamera.distance, duration: 4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```